# Setting MALLOC_ARENA_MAX value in development.rb, production.rb etc in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-management

Can we set the property `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` in the Rails environment files (like `development.rb`)?
Does rails pick up the property when written inside these files?

The way I am setting it (in `development.rb`):

```
ENV["MALLOC_ARENA_MAX"]="2" if ENV["MALLOC_ARENA_MAX"].nil?
```

Comment: Rails has nothing to do with MALLOC_ARENA_MAX (neither does Ruby itself), so this line will have no effect on the process's memory profile. It should be set before you start the Ruby process.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov where exactly do you mean?obviously i can set in environment and it will work for sure .is there not somewhere i can set in ruby code before initialization?